# Receiving a fatal http 500 error when updating wordpress post

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a linux server and when updating posts I receive this error when in debug mode, Any help is greatly appreciated thanks.

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Term could not be converted to string in /public_html/wp-includes/taxonomy.php on line 2285

Comment: Can you post the code in line 2285

Comment: [HTTP 500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error) is a generic server-side error message. Any time you see this your first step should be to check your error logs for more detail.

Comment: Propably not proper PHP version. What PHP version do you have on this server ?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use an object as a string. I think there's a filter or action running in the `save_post` action.

Do you have some custom code using `get_terms` ?

The function has change it's parameter order since WordPress 4.5. See more details [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/)

If you have any plugin or code using this function, try to change, update or desactivate them.